# keras: load saved model weights in a model for evaluation

Tags: keras

I finishing model training processing. During training, I used ModelCheckpint to save the weights of the best model by:

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, 
                         save_best_only=True, mode='max')
```

After training, I load the model weights in to a model for evaluation, but I found the model does not give the best accuracy observed during training. I reload the model as follows:

```
model.load_weights(filepath) #load saved weights
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 7, 7, input_shape=(3, 128, 128)))
....
....
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer=sgd,
          metrics=['accuracy'])

#evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator,val_samples)
print("Accuracy = ", scores[1])
```

The highest accuracy saved by Modelcheckpoint is about 85%, but the re-compiled model only gives an accuracy of 16%?

Is there something wrong I am doing?

To be safe, is there any way to directly save the best model rather than the model weights?

Answer (score 0):

Putting model.load_weights(filepath) after compiling the model fixes the problem!!

But I am still curious about saving the best model during training

Comment: What do you mean by saying saving the best model during training ? The model is not changing while training |: any way if you would like to do that...you can use the flag save_weights_only = False and it will save the model each epoch.... You reminded me about a question I asked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139494/tensorflow-keras-modelcheckpoint-saving-model-while-training-why

Answer (score 0):

Two tips for making sure you're using the best model trained:

## Add the val_acc to the file name

You can create your `ModelCheckpoint` like this:

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('my-model-{val_acc:.2f}.hdf5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, 
                     save_best_only=True, mode='max')
```

That way, you'll have multiple files, and you would be able to make sure you pick the best model.

## Read the training output

When you look at the output of Keras while fitting, you'll see:

```
Epoch 000XX: val_acc improved from 0.8 to 0.85, saving model to my-model-0.85.hdf5
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a bunch of data that you are training on and you decide to save the weights for your best iteration only. Now, if you have not iterated through all of your data before you find your 'best' model weights you will be effectively throwing away data and any later evaluation using the so called best weights will not correlate to your in-batch evaluation.