# TensorFlow.Keras ModelCheckpoint Saving model while training , why?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I was wondering why do we need to save the model while training ?
isn't enough to save it once at the beginning of the train and then only save the weights during the train ?

I mean , The model isn't changing during the train , why this boolean is need for ?

```
class ModelCheckpoint(Callback):
...
save_weights_only: if True, then only the model's weights will be saved.
...
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Its not a need or requirement, its just convenience. In a typical DL/DS workflow, you train a lot of models with different configurations and it is quite easy to get lost. Maybe you now have saved the weights for the best model but you don't remember which model configuration it was used. That information is not part of the weights and has to be recorded separately.

Then Keras provides a simple solution, to store the mode (which takes less than 10 KB) along with the weights, so in the case that you lose the original model configuration, it is still saved in the same HDF5 file.

Also consider the case where you send the model weights to someone else without the model configuration, how can you load the weights without a model? Again its just convenience.

Comment: I understand it , that's why I am saving the model configurations/properties and structure once before starting the train,I will clear my question : Why to do the same operation each epoch if its enough to do it once before starting the train ? This boolean is wrong programming and caused a bug while using  multi GPU training function provided by Keras . https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8123

Comment: @StavBodik No, its not wrong, the bug has nothing to do with this particular option. It was introduced way before parallel models existed.

Comment: Saving same data to file inside loop is wrong, if this boolean was not exist everything would be better, I accept this is not a bug , But this caused problem when using multi GPU functionality which Keras providing because it's trys to save the model in each epoch of the parallel system. And now I don't know if its safe just to ignore this boolean and set it to True forever.